# Need to add the number of completes per interviewer in two union'ed queries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database per project. Currently I select each interviewer and then add up the results on their surveys to get the num_completes. I need to do this on multiple projects and add the num_completes each interview had. Here is my code so far:

```
SELECT interviewer AS INTERVIEWER, COUNT(completes) AS NUM_COMPLETES
    FROM tableone_projectone, interviewertable_mainsystemdb
    WHERE survey_result = '01' AND interviewertablekey=interviewernumber
    GROUP BY survey_result, interviewer
UNION ALL
 SELECT interviewer AS INTERVIEWER, COUNT(completes) AS NUM_COMPLETES
    FROM tableone_projecttwo, interviewertable_mainsystemdb
    WHERE survey_result = '01' AND interviewertablekey=interviewernumber
    GROUP BY survey_result, interviewer
    ORDER BY INTERVIEWER DESC
    GO
```

I had to sanitize my query so sorry if it doesn't make much sense.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Lucent Fox basically has the right answer, but you want to also remember to move your ORDER BY clause to the outside of the query. This would make the full answer:

```
SELECT INTERVIEWER, Sum(NUM_COMPLETES) FROM (
    SELECT interviewer AS INTERVIEWER, COUNT(completes) AS NUM_COMPLETES
        FROM tableone_projectone, interviewertable_mainsystemdb
        WHERE survey_result = '01' AND interviewertablekey=interviewernumber
        GROUP BY survey_result, interviewer
    UNION ALL
    SELECT interviewer AS INTERVIEWER, COUNT(completes) AS NUM_COMPLETES
        FROM tableone_projecttwo, interviewertable_mainsystemdb
        WHERE survey_result = '01' AND interviewertablekey=interviewernumber
        GROUP BY survey_result, interviewer
) AS unions 
GROUP BY INTERVIEWER 
ORDER BY INTERVIEWER DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a derived table:

```
SELECT INTERVIEWER, Sum(NUM_COMPLETES) 
FROM (...) AS unions 
GROUP BY INTERVIEWER
```

Place all of your unions in place of the ...